# Downloading and uploading files from OneDrive using MS Drive API

Tags: python, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I've created an Azure app to update OneDrive files automatically via Python. I want it to enter someone else's drive and download files from or upload files there. However, I'm struggling forming the correct request link.

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
r = requests.post(f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive", headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer "+at, "content-type":"Application/Json"}) #at = authorization token
```

and get the error

'{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "BadRequest",\r\n    "message": "Empty Payload. JSON content expected.",\r\n    "innerError": {\r\n      "date": "2021-02-01T07:52:02",\r\n      "request-id": "6d159ace-252a-41a3-8805-dad6cd633348",\r\n      "client-request-id": "6d159ace-252a-41a3-8805-dad6cd633348"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}'

I'd like to enter one drive with link like this: https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/someemail_xxx_ru/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx

How should I form the request?

Answer (score 0):

You just sent a post request to the endpoint, but in this request, you did not specify other required information, such as directory, source file object, etc.These informations should be included in the json carried in the request.By the way, your endpoint also seems to be missing your onddrive path

Here's [exampel document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content?view=odsp-graph-online)

you can using python like this:

```
requests.post(  
    '<endpoint>',
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + <token>, 'Content-type': 'application/json'},
    data=json.dumps(<json_information>).json())
```

Fill in the <> with your information